# After using another amd card PC won't boot throwing exceptions in Xorg.0.log

Tags: 14.04, boot, ati, xorg, segmentation-fault

I wanted to test my second AMD card that I have (270X Gigabyte) instead of my current (280X Gigabyte) and after plugging it in the PCIE port and powering on the machine I got a 'blinking beacon' and no boot. After booting into recovery root shell and copying/reading logs I got to Xorg.0.log which looked like so:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/10148719/

Where the most interesting part is here:

```
[   220.868] (II) Module glesx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   220.868]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 1.0.0
[   220.868] Loading extension GLESX
[   220.868] (II) fglrx(0): GLESX enableFlags = 8784
[   220.869] (II) fglrx(0): GLESX is enabled
[   220.869] (II) LoadModule: "amdxmm"
[   220.869] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/modules/amdxmm.so
[   220.870] (II) Module amdxmm: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   220.870]    compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 2.0.0
[   220.891] (EE) 
[   220.891] (EE) Backtrace:
[   220.893] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x48) [0x7fb9a82a1798]
[   220.893] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/X (0x7fb9a80f8000+0x1ad489) [0x7fb9a82a5489]
[   220.893] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fb9a71f5000+0x10340) [0x7fb9a7205340]
...........
[   220.895] (EE) 26: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/extra-modules.dpkg-tmp/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so (xdl_xs115_atiddxScreenInit+0xe37) [0x7fb9a327ab07]
[   220.895] (EE) 27: /usr/bin/X (AddScreen+0x71) [0x7fb9a814de91]
[   220.895] (EE) 28: /usr/bin/X (InitOutput+0x3c8) [0x7fb9a818f078]
[   220.895] (EE) 29: /usr/bin/X (0x7fb9a80f8000+0x598ab) [0x7fb9a81518ab]
[   220.895] (EE) 30: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fb9a5c34ec5]
[   220.895] (EE) 31: /usr/bin/X (0x7fb9a80f8000+0x44efe) [0x7fb9a813cefe]
[   220.895] (EE) 
[   220.895] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
[   220.895] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   220.895] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
[   220.895] (EE) 
[   220.895] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   220.895] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   220.895] (EE) 
[   220.944] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

What is wrong in here? I have tried resetting the BIOS but that didn't help.

Comment: What is the content of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` if any ? Shouldn't you regenerate xorg.conf with some amd tool like `aitconfig` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ubuntu 14.10 64 bits I faced out the same errors after upgrade. So I performed the following commands and it's working now.

On the console (Ctrl+Alt+F1)

Uninstall and remove all configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Install the proprietary package on Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

Create a new xorg.conf

```
sudo aticonfig --initial
```

Restart the PC

```
sudo reboot
```

So, After the system splashscreen, the lightdm greeter must be displayed.